# error 501 while calling api with retrofit android

Tags: android, okhttp, server-error

I have searched various SO threads for the same but no results. anyways, I am having trouble calling simple rest api with retrofit. It is a patch api and when I call it from swagger it works fine and response is sent. but when I call from android it doesn't work. I have another similar api request but it works fine with android code as well. please check below details and guide me where I am going wrong.

**API Call in Swagger**

Request url : http://138.197.110.214:3100/register/resendVerificationCode

Parameters :

```
{
  "email": "ab@gmail.com",
  "requestForNewPassword": true,
  "sendMail": true
}
```

Response

```
{
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "date": "Wed, 07 Feb 2018 21:35:48 GMT",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "content-encoding": "gzip",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "vary": "accept-encoding"
}
```

**Below is the details for android call**

Declaration in interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @PATCH("/register/resendVerificationCode")
    public Observable<ResendOTPResponse> doResendForgetOTP(@Field("email") String email, @Field(WebServicesTags.TAG_STR_requestForNewPassword) boolean request, @Field("sendMail") boolean emailbool);
```

Method call in class

```
Observable<ResendOTPResponse> register =  apiservice.doResendForgetOTP(edtUsername.getText().toString(), true, true);        register.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())                .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
Toast.makeText(mContext, "" + mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.msg_networkerror), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return Observable.empty();
})
.subscribe(new Observer<ResendOTPResponse>() {
@Override
public void onCompleted() {
pdi.dismiss();
}
@Override
public void onError(Throwable e) {
((HttpException) e).code();
}
@Override
public void onNext(ResendOTPResponse resendOTPResponse) {
otpRestricter.setCounter(otpRestricter.getCounter() + 1);
showOTPDialog(mContext, 1);
}
});
```

Logcat output

```
D/OkHttp: --> PATCH http://138.197.110.214:3100/register/resendVerificationCode HTTP/1.1
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 63
D/OkHttp: email=ahah%40xjxjx.com&requestForNewPassword=true&sendMail=true
D/OkHttp: --> END PATCH (63-byte body)
.
.
.
D/OkHttp: <-- 501 Not Implemented http://138.197.110.214:3100/register/resendVerificationCode (903ms)
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/vnd.wap.wml
D/OkHttp: Proxy-Connection: close
D/OkHttp: Connection: close
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 200
D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1518040494521
D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1518040495105
D/OkHttp: <?xml version="1.0"?>
D/OkHttp: <!DOCTYPE wml PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.1//EN"
D/OkHttp:  "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml_1.1.xml">
D/OkHttp: <wml><card id = "error" title = "Error 400">
D/OkHttp: <p>
D/OkHttp:   Bad Request
D/OkHttp: </p>
D/OkHttp: </card></wml>
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (200-byte body)
```

Comment: You’re getting a 400 bad request, I notice you’re output from logcat has the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, is this correct? Should it just be application/json as in the Swagger request?

Comment: @GaryO'Donoghue i have other apis implemented in similar way and they are working fine and returning json. it is this specific request that is causing problem

Comment: Then I would maybe capture what swagger is sending to the API using a packet sniffer like wireshark/fiddler and compare that to what you’re sending from the device. Also if you got the request working in a rest client like Postman you can see what it’s actually sending from there too, might be easier than on the device as you can alter the request easily. One last thing, just maybe hard-code the request body from the android program to match swagger so at least you’re comparing like with like, and there isn’t any special characters causing an issue

Comment: sure will do that.